# ISO 369 (german) != 639 (english)

Tags: translation, iso

I found two translations of one article at:

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-2or3.en.html

> began with either a ISO 639-1 two-letter language code or ISO 639-2 three-letter code

vs

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-2or3.de.html

> begannen entweder mit einem zweibuchstabigen Code nach ISO 369-1 oder einem dreibuchstabigen Code nach ISO 369-2

Have there ever been a ISO 369-x what have been changed to ISO 639-x?

I have a table SYSTEM_LANGUAGE having a field ISO_369_CODE.

```
SYSTEM_LANGUAGE
+----+--------------+
| id | iso_369_code |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | en           |
+----+--------------+
```

Is the field named correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** the field is named incorrectly [International standard 369](https://www.iso.org/standard/53391.html) it is about something else:

ISO 369:2009 Machine tools - Symbols for indications appearing on machine tools